# How to perform a cumulative sum of distinct values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id    date         company    ......
123   2019-01-01        A
224   2019-01-01        B
345   2019-01-01        B
987   2019-01-03        C
334   2019-01-03        C
908   2019-01-04        C
765   2019-01-04        A
554   2019-01-05        A
482   2019-01-05        D
```

and I want to get the cumulative number of unique values over time for the 'company' column. So if a company appears at a later date they are not counted again.

My expected output is:

```
date            cumulative_count
2019-01-01      2
2019-01-03      3
2019-01-04      3
2019-01-05      4
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['date']).company.nunique().cumsum()
```

but this double counts if the same company appears on a different date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `duplicated` + `cumsum` + `last`

```
m = df.duplicated('company')
d = df['date']

(~m).cumsum().groupby(d).last()
```

```
date
2019-01-01    2
2019-01-03    3
2019-01-04    3
2019-01-05    4
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way try to fix anky_91

```
(df.company.map(hash)).expanding().apply(lambda x: len(set(x)),raw=True).groupby(df.date).max()
Out[196]: 
date
2019-01-01    2.0
2019-01-03    3.0
2019-01-04    3.0
2019-01-05    4.0
Name: company, dtype: float64
```

From anky_91

```
(df.company.astype('category').cat.codes).expanding().apply(lambda x: len(set(x)),raw=True).groupby(df.date).max()
```

Comment: @anky_91 hash is just like what you did for factorized :-)

Answer (score 1):

This takes more code than anky's answer, but still works for the sample data:

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
(df.drop_duplicates(['company'])
   .groupby('date')
   .size().cumsum()
   .reindex(df['date'].unique())
   .ffill()
)
```

Output:

```
date
2019-01-01    2.0
2019-01-03    3.0
2019-01-04    3.0
2019-01-05    4.0
dtype: float64
```