# How to do a cumulative sum of distinct values over 2 columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumulative-sum

I want to find cumulative sum for a column on group by of 2 columns. I want to get the cumulative number of unique values over time for the 'name' column. So if a name appears at a later date they are not counted again.

I have a data frame like this:

```
date           company   names
2019-01-01        A      Joe
2019-01-01        B      Bill
2019-01-01        B      Ben
2019-01-03        C      Candy
2019-01-03        C      Cindy
2019-01-04        C      Cindy
2019-01-04        A      Julia
2019-01-05        A      Joe
2019-01-05        D      Daniel
```

My expected Output:

```
date           company   Cumulative name count
2019-01-01        A       1
2019-01-01        B       2     
2019-01-03        C       2      
2019-01-04        C       2
2019-01-04        A       2
2019-01-05        A       2
2019-01-05        D       1
```

I came across this question on stack overflow: [How to perform a cumulative sum of distinct values in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807505/how-to-perform-a-cumulative-sum-of-distinct-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

I followed this solution for this link for cumulative sum over one column i.e. date:

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
(df.drop_duplicates(['name'])
   .groupby('date')
   .size().cumsum()
   .reindex(df['date'].unique())
   .ffill()
)
```

Like name count for date column only:

```
    date          Cumulative name count
    2019-01-01     3    
    2019-01-03     5
    2019-01-04     6
    2019-01-05     7
```

But i want to do it for both data and company column now. If i include the company column in the group by it is not giving me the right numbers still.Is there a similar to do this cumulative sum over 2 columns for unique name cumulative count?

Comment: Why last two A return 2 ?

Comment: Because there is an entry for company A on 2019-01-05. But as the name is repeating so count remains 2. As i want unique name count only. If there was a new name then the count would have increased to 3.

Comment: Also why 01-01 B have count 2 ?

Comment: Because i am trying to get cumulative unique count not a simple unique name count. Look at this for difference between count and cumulative count: https://openspecimen.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CAT/pages/127893528/What+is+difference+between+aggregate+functions+count+and+cumulative+count

Comment: 2019-01-01 B have 2 uniques names so the name count for it is 2.

Comment: The logic here is counter each other ~ Good Luck

Comment: the question and the dataset is a duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807505/how-to-perform-a-cumulative-sum-of-distinct-values-in-pandas-dataframe